# Append multiple CSVs Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have multiple CSVs with same data structures in all these.
All i want is to append all these in one or to create a separate master CSV in which all the records from all files will be stored.

Note: I don't want to use any of the dataframe like pandas or dask or any.

Can somebody help me out?

Thanks

Comment: Please show the CSV structure as well

Comment: Please consider 3 simple csv.

Answer (score 0):

```py
# append option
for csv_file in csv_files:
    with open(csv_file, 'r') as f:
        data = f.readlines()[1:]
    with open(master_file, 'a') as f:
        f.write(data)
```

Note- You will need to add header line to the master_csv before loop

Comment: When we do this. I guess it takes the header from all csv and append that too. Does it??

Comment: edited accordingly. Header will be skipped now

Comment: When doing the same f.write expect data as str. So getting an error. I tried doing str(data) too but it puts the data in csv as lists. Any chance here?